# Rationality of sum of roots (or rational function thereof) of a system of algebraic equations.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

I am looking for a reference/hints of proof towards statements of the kind;

Given an irreducible system of $n$ polynomial equations over $\mathbb Q$ in $n$ variables
$$P_i(x_1,...,x_n)=0,\quad i=1,...,n\,,$$
with $k$ (generally) complex solutions $\sigma_1,...,\sigma_k$, the following is true.

For any $P$ and $Q$ polynomials (*edit : in $n$ variables) over $\mathbb Q$, the following sum is an element of $\mathbb Q$;
$$\sum_{a=1}^k \frac{P(\sigma_a)}{Q(\sigma_a)}\in \mathbb Q\,.$$

I suppose that it is possible to prove this by hand in the simpler case of purely polynomial sums, I have no clue for the rational-function case.

Comment: That's clearly false - take $Q$ to be the constant polynomial $1$ and let $P(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=x_i$, so that
$$\sum_{a=1}^k\frac{P(\sigma_a)}{Q(\sigma_a)}=\sigma_i$$
which, as you said yourself, is in general some tuple of complex numbers with no reason to be rational.

Comment: But $P$ is a polynomial in one variable ?

Comment: A solution to a polynomial equation in $n$ variables is an $n$-tuple of numbers. You said *"Given an irreducible system of $n$ polynomial equations over $\mathbb{Q}$ in $n$ variables"*.

Comment: Indeed... Sorry for this. So I guess I should sharpen the statement and ask for a bit more symmetry, like $P/Q$ be a rationnal function of somme symmetric combinations of the roots. But then in one variable this is clearly true, it shouldn't be hard to obtain it also for $n$ variables.

Comment: So, you're looking for a version of [Vieta's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) that applies to a system of equations instead of a single equation?

Comment: Yes I suppose this would be a good start for me to understand really this case. Thanks for naming Vieta's formulas I didn't know that these kind of identities had this name !

Comment: I keep on correcting my comments, apologies; the answer to the comment by curious is actually that his example is not quite correct; I'd like indeed a counter example if any to his proposition; taking $Q=1$ and $P(x_1,…,x_n)=x_i$. The sum is then not $\sigma_i$ but rather the sum of the $i$-th component of $\sigma_i$. In all examples I tried the property worked.